# How do I enable Japanese and Chinese text in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, japanese

I have installed Ubuntu Server on my old laptop. It is terminal-only. I figured out how to enable Cyrillic characters display using `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`. But I can't find a way to enable Japanese and Chinese characters display.

Similar problem I think is that `telnet mapscii.me` also displays much better on Gnome Terminal that is in raw terminal (you can access it in your GUI system using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open `$HOME/.bashrc`. Using vi, for example:

```
vi .bashrc
```

Add these lines:

```
case $TERM in
    linux) LANG=C ;;
    *) LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 ;;
esac
```